Есть ли стандартная библиотека которая сможет обновить вложенные словари?
Есть ли стандартная библиотека, которая сможет обновить вложенные словари:
old_dict = {'a': {'b': 1}, 'c': {'d': 2}}
new_dict = {'a': {'f': 3}, 'g': {'h': 4}}

old_dict.update(**new_dict)

print(old_dict)  # Выведет {'a': {'f': 3}, 'c': {'d': 2}, 'g': {'h': 4}}
# Желал увидеть {'a': {'b': 1, 'f': 3}, 'c': {'d': 2}, 'e': {'f': 3}, 'g': {'h': 4}}

Или единственный способ - это мне рекурсивно бежать по ключам и значениям и искать чего не хватает и добавлять?

Ну да, это явно не простое обновление значений по ключам. У вас сложнее логика

@Komdosh, жаль, печаль, тоска.... Пойду тогда рекурсию писать...

@Алексей может лучше циклом?

@Amgarak если неограниченная вложенность возможна, то циклом можно разве что с эмуляцией стека.

@insolor будет чуть больше кода, но зато надёжней.

import pandas as pd
old_dict = {'a': {'b': 1}, 'c': {'d': 2}}
new_dict = {'a': {'f': 3}, 'g': {'h': 4}}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(old_dict)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(new_dict)
res = pd.concat([df1, df2]).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).dropna().to_dict()).to_dict()

res:
{'a': {'b': 1.0, 'f': 3.0}, 'c': {'d': 2.0}, 'g': {'h': 4.0}}


Спасибо,  приму ответ, раз предложили, но я уже через множества и рекурсию реализовал =)
